# Prepend text to a given link and open it

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm making a simple javascript/html code where:

- The user type in a link (e.g `www.example.com` and clicks enter).
- A javascript code prepends the text `view-source:https://`.
- The source code of the chosen website is opened.

How would I get about doing this?

Comment: Show us your code so far...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Comment: You will not be allowed to run such a script in for ex Chrome: https://plungjan.name/SO/viewsource.html

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I did this for you, I don't know if you get difficulty in writing question or other things. But, always please do good research and write your own codes and come in stackoverflow after some difficulty. I was writing this answer expecting you will edit your question, now I don't want to discard the answer so.

It is quite easy to do. I will do from the javascript part. After the user entered the location, lets say function location_entered function is called:-

```js
function location_entered() {
  const loc = document.getElementById("location").value;
  // If you want to open view source page in new tab
  window.open('view-source:' + loc, '_blank');
  // If in same tab
  // window.location.replace('view-source:' + loc); // http redirection
  // window.location.href('view-source:' + loc); // anchor link clicked like functionality
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="location_entered()">
  <input type="text" id="location" />
</form>
```

*Note:- I don't know the universality of the `view-source` as I have tested in chrome and firefox, I can only say for these two browsers.

Comment: Please next time, test your code. 1. Missing quote after _blank 2. not using var or const on location will attempt to overwrite the window.location object, you do NOT want to do that just before you try to access location.href. 3. The code will not run here in a stacksnippet so I did not save as a stack snippet. 4.The browser will not allow to load view-source from a script since it considers it a local resource

Comment: Not necessary- just use snippets or external urls if a snippet will not run